# R sprintf maximal input length

Tags: r, replace

R's `sprintf` has preset maximal input length set as 8192 bytes:

```
sprintf(x, y)
Error in sprintf(x, y) : 'fmt' length exceeds maximal format length 8192
```

what is the workaround for longer input strings? I learned that in C there is [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) function for such cases, but this seems not to be available in R, isn't it?

*Example*

The input file is something like

```
select *
from some_table
where a = '%s' and
      b = %d and
      c in (%s) and
      d = %s and
      e >= %0.2f
```

but *much* more complicated and *much* longer. I need to replace all the values with some values. `sprintf` is great for that but one of the input scripts I am working with is too long. I need multiple different arguments to be replaced and the arguments have different formats (string, double, float). The values to be replaced are located in different parts of the input file so I need to search and replace them in given order. I know about [this approach](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/vignettes/Parameterized_SQL_queries.html) to parametrized queries, but need to use different library (`RPostgreSQL`).

Comment: You may sometimes to replace `sprintf` with functions such as `paste`, for example. Can't you make a specific minimal example?

Comment: Further parametrize your format string?

Comment: @James I don't understand what you mean..?

Comment: For example, `select * from long_table_name where ...` becomes `select * from %s where ...`

Comment: @James The example resembles my real life problem, there are strings and numbers to replace, the replacement values are in most cases short strings (say <100 characters).

Comment: @Tim What I am saying is you can slice up the fixed parts into chunks and feed them in as strings too, even though they don't change, how long is your current format string?

Comment: @James I understand and was considering this but the input is composed of multiple lines and multiple values stored in different places are to be replaced; also I would like to generalize this to other cases, so cutting the file into peaces is not practical in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a little function that cuts the `fmt` argument into smaller pieces, looks up the variables that are associated to the `%...` expressions, and then calls `sprintf` for each of these pieces. `match.call` is used to get the arguments that are hidden in `...`. `sprintf` is called via `do.call`, because a priori we don't know which of the further arguments in `...` belong to the current piece of `fmt`.
The function is not at all perfect. For example so far `fmt` is cut into pieces of fixed length. In general this doesn't work because you have to keep the `%...` expressions intact. To see if it works, I left the result as a list of strings.

```
f <- function(N, fmt, ...)
{
  cl <- as.list(match.call())
  n <- nchar(fmt)
  p <- which(unlist(strsplit(fmt,""))=="%")

  result <- list()

  for ( i in 0:(n%/%N))
  {
    start <- i*N+1
    end   <- min((i+1)*N,n)
    fm <- substr(fmt,start,end)
    k <- which(p %in% (start:end))
    v <<- c(list(fm),cl[k+3])
    result[[i+1]] <- do.call("sprintf", v )
  }

  return(result)
}
```

A small example using pieces of length 10:

```
> f( 10, "xyz: %i -ää %s 3 %i %f );", 3, "+++", 12, 0.123 )
[[1]]
[1] "xyz: 3 -ä"

[[2]]
[1] "ä +++ 3 12 "

[[3]]
[1] "0.123000 );"

> paste(f( 10, "xyz: %i -ää %s 3 %i %f );", 3, "+++", 12, 0.123 ),collapse="")
[1] "xyz: 3 -ää +++ 3 12 0.123000 );"
```

> 

Perhaps one can use regular expressions to detect the `%...`'s and find the right cutting points.