# How to solve the 'fmt' length exceeds maximal format length 8192 Error while reading a csv file?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, dataset, jupyter

I am new to R. I am trying to read a csv file in Jupyter notebook but I get the following error. Would pleas help me solve it in a simple way? Thank you.

`df <- read.csv(file = '../datasets/federalist/federalist-papers.csv', header = TRUE)`

and the error is:

```
`ERROR while rich displaying an object: Error in sprintf(wrap, header, body): 'fmt' length exceeds maximal format length 8192

Traceback:
1. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
2. tryCatch(withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler), error = outer_handler)
3. tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
4. tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
5. doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
6. withCallingHandlers({
 .     if (!mime %in% names(repr::mime2repr)) 
 .         stop("No repr_* for mimetype ", mime, " in repr::mime2repr")
 .     rpr <- repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
 .     if (is.null(rpr)) 
 .         return(NULL)
 .     prepare_content(is.raw(rpr), rpr)
 . }, error = error_handler)
7. repr::mime2repr[[mime]](obj)
8. repr_latex.data.frame(obj)
9. repr_matrix_generic(obj, sprintf("\\begin{tabular}{%s}\n%%s%%s\\end{tabular}\n", 
 .     cols), "%s\\\\\n\\hline\n", "  &", " %s &", "%s", "\t%s\\\\\n", 
 .     "%s &", " %s &", escape_fun = latex_escape_vec, ...)
10. sprintf(wrap, header, body)`
```

Comment: That's the only line in your notebook? It looks like it's trying to print the result for some reason. I wouldn't expect that if you assign to `df` like you are. Is this a very large CSV file?

Comment: Look at this Question & Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862507/r-sprintf-maximal-input-length

Comment: or maybe try to use `readr::read_csv()` from readr package

Comment: or `data.table::fread()`  This looks like a problem with the data.  It might help to take a look at it in notepad.